# How to connect to Windows 10 OpenSSH over tramp?

Tags: tramp

I've installed OpenSSH on a Windows 10 machine, and can connect to it from the Linux command line with `ssh` or `scp`, giving the `cmd.exe` "shell". But tramp hangs on `Waiting for prompts from remote shell`:

```
Tramp: Opening connection for win using ssh...
Tramp: Sending command ‘exec ssh   -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none win’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed
Tramp: Opening connection for win using ssh...failed
```

also with `(setq tramp-use-ssh-controlmaster-options nil)`

```
Tramp: Opening connection for win using ssh...
Tramp: Sending command ‘exec ssh    -e none win’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed
Tramp: Opening connection for win using ssh...failed
```

Is there some special trick?

---

I've tried [changing the Windows OpenSSH shell to bash](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration#configuring-the-default-shell-for-openssh-in-windows), which makes regular ssh-ing and git cloning nicer, but doesn't seem to help tramp.

I've also tried both

```
 (setq explicit-shell-file-name "cmd"
       explicit-cmd-args '("/q"))
```

and

```
 (setq explicit-shell-file-name "powershell"
       explicit-powershell-args '("-file" "-"))
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use method `sftp`:

```
/sftp:WhoYou@WinHost:/C:/Users/WhoYou/SomeFile.txt
```

WFM as of this morning, using Emacs 26.1 on Linux Mint Debian Edition 2 -- so both quite old. Anything more up-to-date should at least be able to do the same.